# Cart page - Get Related Product with URLs (including the category)

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, related-products

For each product in the cart I'm loading its related products.

```
$related_product_collection = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection()
                                        ->addUrlRewrite()
                                        ->AddStoreFilter();
```

But I'm getting the URL of these related products without the category name

```
<?php echo $relatedProduct->getProductUrl(); ?>
```

I'm getting

http://myDomain/product1 instead of http://myDomain/categ1/product1

The courses can belong to several categories.

What's the best approach here? Add a rewrite manually?
http://myDomain/product1 --> redirects to --> http://myDomain/cat1/product1

Add a loop through all the categories to get the right one for that related product?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I eventually fixed this problem.

```
<?php foreach ($unique_related_products as $id) {
    $relatedProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $relatedProduct->setDoNotUseCategoryId(false);
    $categoryCollection = $relatedProduct->getCategoryCollection();
    Mage::register('current_category', $categoryCollection->getFirstItem());
?>  

 <a href="<?php echo $relatedProduct->getProductUrl(); ?>">

<?php 
    Mage::unregister('current_category'); //reset the registry to previous state.
}?>
```

I'm getting the 1st category of each product to compose the product URL.
Not sure it's the best solution though.